# When do we use 'Theories' in JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

Some tests are used with this annotation @RunWith(Theories.class) in JUnit and I don't      know when and why we use it?

Comment: Basically, if you want to execute the same test multiple times with different inputs.

Comment: This post provided some cool insight to theories: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2010/02/07/junit-theories/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use them when you would like your tests to focus on the generalized relationship between inputs and outputs. See: https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/junit_theories.

Comment: I would suggest that a relationship b/w inputs and outputs would be better defined by `@Paramaterized` where the input and output can be specified. In `@Theories` setting up the input to output relationship is not natural. I would suggest it is more common when there are multiple possible inputs that result in the same output or where the output can be calculated from the unput. Notice that in the blog you posted, the output is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think capturing multiple types of input are one thing. The high level idea is that you want to test if your method is true for all possible inputs.

For example, let's say I have some complex business process that takes 5 different inputs, and let's say for each input, there's 10 possible states, so we end up with 10*10*10*10*10 = 100,000 possible input states, which means we need to know beforehand what all these 100,000 output values are.

However, you probably realize that you don't need to actually enumerate all 100,000 states. There's probably a subset that you are interested in. Let's theorize for example:

"Admins have no permission restriction". And if I wanted to assert that this is true, my Test ends up looking like the pseudo-code below.

```
@Test
public void AdminsHaveNoPermissionRestriction(User user, BusinessProcess bp, Input a, Input b ...) {
   Assume.assumeThat("User is an admin", user.hasRole(admin);

   // .. rest of test which uses bp, a, b etc...
)
```

The nice thing is that we skip un-interested objects (non-admins) because it fails the assumptions.